# Android: Need to communicate between two applications using HTTP requests

Tags: java, android, http, router

I have an application made by another company that use HTTP requests to communicate with our android application.

Their app use some static URL like:

> `http://FAKELINK/service1`
>
> `http://FAKELINK/service2`
>
> `http://FAKELINK/service3`

Each url they call have some POST data as well, my application need somehow to see that this application is calling `http://FAKELINK/service1` and return the expected data without any online interaction. There is any library i can use to make this happen?

Comment: "need somehow to see that this application is calling http://FAKELINK/service1 and return the expected data without any online interaction" -- Not entirely sure what you need here. Please clarify.

Comment: First of all you need to setup intent filters for the fake links so the android system would call your receiver when the other app sends a request. It is not a real http communication, but more like linking between apps. Not sure tho why not using content providers in the first place, but that is a different story.